# iPhone 4s Lock/Power Button Sticky

Tags: iphone, hardware

I am using an old 4S and the Power Button is kind of half stuck down. Are there any hints or tricks out there to un-stuck it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of is using Assistive Touch, which allows you to lock your device without ever actually touching the lock button.  Other than that, I would say just get the button replaced or buy a new phone - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Same tragedy happens with me as well , one month ago, my iPhone 4S absolutely broke and I was not able to access it again, fortunately My elder bro had another iphone that was just swapped out with the motherboard. As per my knowledge the Buttons only work for a short time I easily replaced it.